Application Insights sometimes does not show the query from a SQL call
I have a Blazor server application with 2 databases it calls via Entity Frameworks. One is the Identity Library DB. The other is my application DB.
When I go in to Application Insights and:

Click on the Application map
Click on the SQL Server (2)
Click Investigate performance

It now under Dependency Name lists the 2 databases.

I select one of the dependencies
I click Drill into

Now over on the right it has Select a sample dependency
If I click on one from the Identity Library database, on the right it has:

Dependency Properties
Custom properties
Command - this has the query run
Related Items

But if I click on one from the application database, then over on the right, for the command, it has the following:
louishowe.database.windows.net,1433 | Application_2024_04_25

That's the server & database. But no query. Why not? What do I have to do so Application Insights can show me the actual queries?

Have you checked out this answer?

Hope this is resolved with the previous question.Are you still looking for the sol?

@Harshitha that fixed it - thank you

@DavidThielen - Please post your sol as an answer or you can delete the thread if you feel it is not required.

@decius If you  make your comment an answer I am happy to select it.

Full SQLQuery is not collected by default, and requires explicit opt-in. The following doc has instructions on how to do that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#advanced-sql-tracking-to-get-full-sql-query

First off, thanks for entering the answer. Second, can you point to the documentation for the applicationInsights.config file too? It says to add to it, but nothing about where that goes or what else is set in it. TIA

Its in the same doc, pasting here for easy reference:


true

